# Embed 'ad hoc' function in SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to format a partial date (the difference between two dates) in HH:MM format.

To do so, I assembled the following logic:

```
LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC((DATE_DIFFERENCE) * 24),'00')) || ':' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(MOD(ROUND((DATE_DIFFERENCE)*24*60),60),'00'))
```

I need to apply this logic to a number of intervals, so it would be nice to key things DRY by using a function.

Is there a way to embed this logic (perhaps using Java) in a SQL statement without having to resort to creating an Oracle function?

** edit **

The DATE_DIFFERENCE can be negative and greater than 24 hours.  I would like to include the sign if negative, but also represent the difference in hours and minutes, even if the DATE_DIFFERENCE is > 24 hours.

Comment: This logic is incorrect, e.g. when DATE_DIFFERENCE = 59 min 59 sec

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - good spot; I've added that data point to the examples in my answer to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating the oracle function?

Comment: @Brian, the client's change-control process is a pain.  I really wanted a simple, but reusable, solution.

Comment: Is DATE_DIFFERENCE a date?  If I execute: select
LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC((sysdate) * 24),'00')) || ':' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(MOD(ROUND((sysdate)*24*60),60),'00')) from dual

I get ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Comment: @Brian, DATE_DIFFERENCE is the difference between to `DATE` fields, so it would be a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Java function accessible from a query would be considerably more work than an SQL function, so I'm not entirely sure what you mean. You can't declare a function with a query as you'd be mixing SQL and PL/SQL contexts.

Your conversion looks unnecessarily complicated; you could do this:

```
substr(numtodsinterval(date_difference, 'DAY'), 12, 5)
```

The [`numtodsinterval` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions117.htm) takes your date difference and converts it to an interval datatype, and the `substr` gets the section that covers the hours and minutes.

It behaves slightly differently though, as it will truncate rather than round the minutes:

```
with tmp as (
    select to_date('2013-04-11 13:17:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        - to_date('2013-04-11 12:57:38', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        as date_difference
    from dual
    union all
    select to_date('2013-04-11 11:11:35', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        - to_date('2013-04-10 22:40:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    from dual
    union all
    select to_date('2013-04-11 00:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        - to_date('2013-04-11 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    from dual
)
select LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC((DATE_DIFFERENCE) * 24),'00')) || ':' ||
        LTRIM(TO_CHAR(MOD(ROUND((DATE_DIFFERENCE)*24*60),60),'00')),
    substr(numtodsinterval(date_difference, 'DAY'), 12, 5)
from tmp;

LTRIM(T SUBSTR(NUMTODSINTERV
------- --------------------
00:20   00:19
12:31   12:30
00:00   00:59
```

The full interval for those is:

```
NUMTODSINTERVAL(DATE_DIFFERENCE,'DAY')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000000 00:19:37.000000000
+000000000 12:30:50.000000000
+000000000 00:59:59.000000000
```

So clearly the first one would round to `00:20`, but truncate to `00:19`. As Egor Skriptunoff noted in comments, your calculation for the third one gives you an incorrect answer, which is why I've included it now.

This will round the minutes but is a bit longer:

```
to_char(round(date '2001-01-01' + date_difference, 'MI'), 'HH24:MI')
```

The actual date used in the literal, where I've used `date '2001-01-01'`, doesn't matter, it can be any day, and you could use `trunc(sysdate)` instead for example. It just allows you to convert the difference back into a `DATE` object, and you can then use the built-in [`round(date)` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions154.htm) on that. For comparison:

```
with tmp as (...)
select LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC((DATE_DIFFERENCE) * 24),'00')) || ':' ||
        LTRIM(TO_CHAR(MOD(ROUND((DATE_DIFFERENCE)*24*60),60),'00')),
    substr(numtodsinterval(date_difference, 'DAY'), 12, 5),
    to_char(trunc(date '2001-01-01' + date_difference, 'MI'), 'HH24:MI'),
    to_char(round(date '2001-01-01' + date_difference, 'MI'), 'HH24:MI')
from tmp;

LTRIM(T SUBSTR(NUMTODSINTERV TO_CH TO_CH
------- -------------------- ----- -----
00:20   00:19                00:19 00:20
12:31   12:30                12:30 12:31
00:00   00:59                00:59 01:00
```

None of that actually gives you what you want, an embedded ad hoc function, but at least if the logic is clearer then reusing it might not be such a worry. Wrapping it in a SQL function still might not be a terrible option though.

Comment: You might be interested that Oracle 12c will allow you do define functions inside a `with ...` statement. Those functions will only exists for the duration of the statement. Would come in handy in this case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yes, that is very interesting. I really need to start reading up on 12c. Thanks!